# How to transfer word paragraph to excel row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a word document with question and answers. I need to convert this data to an Excel spreadsheet. I need question number, questions, answers, explanation in separate rows. 
Example 
In my word

**1.    A 45-year-old male presented with asthma
What is the likely diagnosis?**
**a.    Yoga

b.  Excercise

c.  CAM

d.  none of these**

In Excel

```
Question no | Question                  | Answer Option          |Ans  
======================================================================
 1          |Is the project up to code? | a.Yoga B.Excercise     | a
=====================================================================
```

Comment: I don't understand your desired data structure

Comment: I have MCQ in word. I need to transfer the data into excel. First Question Number should in A1, Question should in B1, Choices should be in C1 etc

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a wildcard find and replace in Word first.

When copying from Word to Excel, a tab will put text in next column.  Each paragraph will be in new row.

So for each question you want to end up with a paragraph with question number. followed by tab, followed by question text (but not the manual line break at end) followed by tab, then your answers separated by space (instead of manual line break).

After you've done the wildcard find and replace, select your text and copy it to Excel.

NB:  The wildcard search shown assumes always a question and 4 answers (if variation in number of answers, do a 2 stage find and replace instead - where in first round you keep answers with manual line breaks, and then in second stage, replace manual line breaks with space).

[image]